# Using Linked List to represent a Matrix Class

Tags: matrix, linked-list

I'm having trouble initializing the linked list for the matrix based on the parameters I input. So if I input the parameters (3,3) it should actually make make 4x4 so I can use the first column and first row for indexing. and the left top corner node as an entry point.

```
def __init__(self, m, n, default=0):
        self._head = MatrixNode(None)
        for node in range(m - 1):
            node = MatrixNode(0)
            node._right = node
        for node in range(n - 1):
            node = MatrixNode(0)
            node._down = node
```

this is what I have so far but I'm sure its horrible.

Answer (score 0):

At first, it may be useful to know, what a MatrixNode is. I guess you just want to store a value there?

Then i see two linear loops, while a matrix is a n*m data structure. Are you sure, your loops do not need to be nested to initialize your structure correctly?

For linked lists i would expect something like `row.next = nextrow` and `row.startnode.next = nextnode`, i do not see anything like this here.

Having this said, i want to ask you, if you really want to implement a matrix yourself, and in such an object oriented (inefficient!) way.

You can use two-dimensional arrays (`a=[[1,2], [3,4]];a[0][0]==1`) or a good implementation from a numerics library like numpy/scipy.

There you have `numpy.array` for storing n-dimensional data (with nice addressing like `matrix[1,2]` and similiar syntax to matlab) or `numpy.matrix` which is like an array with some methods overloaded for matrix operations (i.e. matrix-matrix multiplication of arrays is pointwise and for matrices it's the usual matrix multiplication).

Comment: Yes MatrixNode is a previous class that the data will be stored in. Regarding row.next = newrow, how will that correspond to the columns. Since each node points down and right?

Comment: Ah, you want both right/bottom pointers, so no explicit rows/columns. This is an option. But really your matrix has a lookup time in O(n+m) for a single item, thats really bad. (At least for dense matrices, for sparse there may be advantages of some formats inefficient for dense matrices).

Answer (score 0):

You are right, its horrible :)
First things first, a linked list is a very bad way of representing a matrix.
If you want to represent a matrix, start with a list of lists, and work from there if that's not enough (see other answer mentioning numpy, for example)

If you want to learn to use linked lists, choose a better example.

Then: you are re-using the variable name "node" for different things:

1. Your loop index. The code `for node in range(...)` will assign an integer from the range to `node` in every iteration.
2. Then you assign a new MatrixNode to `node`, and then you set the node's neighbor (_right or _down) to be not the actual neighbor, but itself (`node._right = node`).

You also never save your nodes that you create inside the loops anywhere, so they will be garbage-collected.

And you never use the optional argument `default`.